# Typescript Definition Files in Webpack

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, vue.js

Okay, so I have a Typescript definition file `model.d.ts`. It contains definitions for the classes used in my business logic, so that I can have strong typing in my Vue.js files.

I have a Vue.js template `person.vue`, with a code section that looks like this:

```
<script lang="ts">
    import axios from "axios";
    import * as _ from "lodash";
    import * as model from "model";
    // ...
</script>
```

But when I try to build this with Webpack, I run into problems:

```
ERROR in I:\git\myapp\src\component\person-page\person.vue.ts
[tsl] ERROR in I:\git\myapp\src\component\person-page\person.vue.ts(27,24)
      TS2307: Cannot find module 'model'.

ERROR in ../myapp/node_modules/ts-loader!../myapp/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0&bustCache!../myapp/src/component/person-page/person.vue
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'model' in 'I:\git\myapp\src\component\person-page'
 @ ../myapp/node_modules/ts-loader!../myapp/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0&bustCache!../myapp/src/component/person-page/person.vue 10:14-30
 @ ../myapp/src/component/person-page/person.vue
 @ ../myapp/src/main.ts
 @ multi webpack-hot-middleware/client ./src/main.ts
```

I'm using `ts-loader`, and the relevant parts of my `webpack.config.js` look like this:

```
module.exports = {
    // ...
    module: {
        rules: [
            // ...
            {
                test: /.ts$/,
                use: {
                    loader: "ts-loader", options: {
                        appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/]
                    }
                },
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            // ...
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: "vue-loader"
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".js", ".vue", ".json"],
        alias: {
            "vue$": "vue/dist/vue.esm.js"
        }
    }
};
```

Why doesn't my definition file work, and how can I make it so that it can be used in `person.vue`?

Comment: I think you need to use a relative path: ```"./model"```

Comment: @BogdanMartinescu that allows me to compile my TS files manually using `tsc`, but webpack's `ts-loader` still gives errors: `ERROR in ../myapp/node_modules/ts-loader!../myapp/src/component/person-page/person.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './model' in 'I:\git\myapp\src\component\person-page'`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem with your path. "model" should point to the complete path to the model.d.ts without the file extensions.